# What kind of ability is activating a magical item: EX, SU, SP, or something else?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

What kind of ability is activating a magical item: EX, SU, SP, or something else?

If there isn't a single answer to this question but it instead depends on the particulars of the item, an explanation of how that rule works is a good answer to this question.

Comment: I have a deleted answer waiting in the wings, but writing it makes me think this is an XY problem - that there's something else that's driving this question that would obviate my answer. Why does it matter whether activating a magical item is EX/SU/SP?

Comment: What is giving you the impression it's any of these? Which rules in particular are confusing you?

Comment: It may be of interest to you that "magic items produce spells or spell-like effects." It is not the same as activating them, just thought it may be relevant (and may be entirely not).

Comment: @annoyingimp that was the question I was trying to ask, thanks for figuring it out!

Comment: I felt it was best to leave the question I asked as-is, rather than edit it, since it did get a correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Activating an item is an action, not an ability. You don't write down "able to activate items" on your character sheet, and you won't find it in any stat block. Activating items is just a thing you can do, like moving, escaping a grapple, or speaking. In fact, on page 142 of the *Player's Handbook*, "Activate Magic Item" is immediately before a separate section, "Use a Special Ability," which goes on to discuss Spell-Like, Supernatural, and Extraordinary Abilities. This clearly shows that activating an item is not a special ability; if it were it would be in the section on special abilities, rather than in a different section.